Need of complex sample analysis for a stratified random sample with clusters
I presented the baseline findings of our cluster-randomised RCT in a cross-sectional paper. The cross-sectional study used stratified random sampling design with clusters as sampling unit. There were 30 clusters in total from 2 strata and total number of participants was 481. I performed bivariate and multivariable logistic regression analyses (not the complex sample analysis). We didn't calculate sampling weights at the beginning.
Is not performing complex sample analysis in a study design like this a big statistical flaw? If anyone could guide me on, how can I address this, that would be great please.
Thank you!
